# get request parameters in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, rest, nosql, tastypie

I am building a REST API for my application that uses a NoSQL db (Neo4j) using Tastypie.

So I overrode some main methods of the class `tastypie.resources.Resource` to do so, and currently struggling to implement `def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):` which is supposed to return a list of objects.

Actually, I want to pass a parameter to this method through the url (something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/airport/?query='aQuery'` ) and then perform a query based on this parameter.

The problem is that the request is `None` so I can't get its parameter !

When printing the kwargs variable, I see this :

```
{'bundle': <Bundle for obj: '<testNeo4Django.testapp.api.Airport object at 0x9d829ac>' and with data: '{}'>}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently positional argument `request` is not passed to`obj_get_list`.

So you should:

```
def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):

    param =  bundle.request.GET['param']
    #fetch objects based on param
    return objects
```

Comment: Thanks, this was changed in TastyPie > 0.9.11. Request used to be passed along and now its part of the bundle (where applicable).