# How to GET the query parameters in Django-Tastypie

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I am building a REST API for my application using Tastypie.

I've gone through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981191/get-request-parameters-in-tastypie) , but it didnt worked.

Actually, I want to pass a parameter to this method through the url (something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/shipments/140119758884542/pptl_id/?DSP=1` ) and then perform a query based on this parameter.

The problem is that I can't get its parameter !

When printing the bundle variable, I see this :

```
<Bundle for obj: 'Shipment object' and with data: '{}'>
```

When printing kwargs variabl, I see this

```
{'pk': u'140119758884542/pptl_id'}
```

How do I get the query parameters?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's request object is kept in the bundle under the property named request.
You can use:

```
bundle.request.GET
```

in order to access the query parameters.
See documentation on the request document [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/)