# Get kwargs in Tastypie custom authorization

Tags: django, tastypie

I would like to get `kwargs` in Tastypie custom authorization. I've to authorize whether user has access to the `id` in URL kwargs.

Authorization methods doesn't seem to pass `kwargs` but passes only `bundle` and `object_list`.

Comment: Not sure to understand why you need kwargs to do what you want to do. Could you explain more please?

Comment: @DavidW. I'm using nested resource api. And need the id passed in the URL just to check whether the user has authorization access to that resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, a custom Authorization does not has **kwargs in the signature.
But you can access URL parameters (like `id`) using `bundle.request`.

This kind of example bellow should work:

```
class RestrictedIdAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        param_id = bundle.request.GET['id']
        accepted_ids = [42, 54, 67] # Must be changed, of course.
        return param_id in accepted_ids
```

You can take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981191/get-request-parameters-in-tastypie) to have another example.